# Most fibers of a fibered surface are non-singular

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a non-singular projective surface and $C$ a non-singular projective curve, both over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $\pi : S \rightarrow C$ be a surjective morphism with connected fibers. The fibers $\pi^{-1}(t)$ for all $t \in C$ are curves. Why are all but finitely many of these fibers non-singular?

Comment: Are you in characteristic zero? Otherwise, it can go wrong.

Comment: Yeah, edited the question to add that. Is there a simple counterexample in positive characteristic?

Comment: For characteristic zero, use the fact that general fiber is smooth (check out generic smoothness). For positive characteristic, if $S\to C$ is any such map, compose with the Frobenius $C\to C$, which keeps the connectedness of fibers, but now all fibers are singular.